# Question (and answers) moved to a beta site ... will it get moved back if the beta fails?

Tags: discussion

If a [question is moved to a beta site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/103930/1655), and the beta site does not get promoted to permanently live, will the question get moved back to the live site?

EDIT - response to questions and comments ...

** I don't object to moving per se .. I object to moving to a site that subsequently goes away and not putting the questions back.  The question, **and the answers which people have put effort into** are effectively deleted.  I think that doesn't show proper respect for the contributors and their contributions.

** Would the question have been closed on Programmers absent the existence of PM?  If no, then the logic of "it doesn't belong and was moved as a courtesy" doesn't really apply.

** I didn't ask the question I linked, but I don't think that it was better suited for PM than for Programmers. In fact I think it was just the opposite. It was a programmer asking if a team of programmers needs a team leader. The programmer is going to want other programmers to answer, not PMs.

Answer (score 4):

**I don't think so**, but I'm not positive either.

If the beta site doesn't go live, I would restructure the question to make it acceptable on a current site.

Comment: That's ridiculous. To move the questions (and answers, which people gave effort to create) to a site that might get eliminated is disrespectful. The question should go back automatically.  It can't be that hard to program.

Comment: @tomjedrz: If the question was moved it didn't belong here anyway. Moving to the beta site was a courtesy.

Answer (score 4):

Josh K got it. Although if the beta site is merged with another instead of just closed, then the questions and answers will be moved over to the "master" site.

We usually don't migrate questions to beta sites for that very reason, except in some cases where the site is still in beta due to having been migrated from an SE 1.0 site (such as answers.onstartups.com) or the question is clearly a poor fit for Programmers.

Questions that would fit here *and* on a more specialized beta site do not get migrated.

Comment: I disagree that the question you moved (which I didn't ask) is a poor fit for Programmers.  In fact, I think you got it backwards in this case. The questioner doesn't want to hear from PMs, he wants to hear from programmers.

Comment: @tomjedrz: but it's not a question about programming or programmers, it's a question about how to manage a project.

Comment: The question was "Does the team need a leader?", which is about the team and the process. My answer was (in essence) "No, but the project needs to be managed." Putting the question on PM **assumes** that, but it shouldn't be assumed. Properly answering the question talks about the development process and why it needs management, which I think is in scope of Programmers.

Comment: @tom that question is off topic here on programmers; it should exist on pm.se or *not at all*